# Merge and compute moving average based on full past and also window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, moving-average

I have 2 dataframes like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_name' : ['ABC', 'ABC','ABC','ABC', 
                  'DEF'],
     'ques_date' : ['13/11/2020', '10/1/2018','11/11/2017', '27/03/2016', 
                '13/05/2010']})

df_score = pd.DataFrame(
    {'stud_name' : ['ABC', 'ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
     'qtr':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q4','Q2','Q4'],
     'year' : [2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2017],
     't_score':[11,13,15,17,12,312,14,15,18,43,32],
     'p_score':[32,45,32,21,56,87,32,786,213,32,11]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) For each `stud_name`, compute two moving average (of t_score) columns as output

`mov_avg_full` = use all past data of a `stud_name`. (all past quarters info from df_score)
`mov_avg_2qtr` = use data from past 2 quarters (only past 2 quarters info from df_score)

ex: if the year is 2020 and it is 3rd qtr, I would like to compute moving average of all past data (before 2020 Q3) and moving average of last 2 quarters (2020 Q1 and 2020 Q2)

If there is no past data for a specific `stud_name`, we just put `NA` (ex: DEF has no past data in df_score)

I tried the below

```
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ques_date'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(by=['stud_name','ques_date'],inplace=True)
df['act_qtr'] = df['ques_date'].dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('Q%q')
df['year'] = df['ques_date'].dt.year
df_score.sort_values(by=['year','qtr'],inplace=True)
df_full = df.merge(df_score,on=['stud_name'])
df_full['mov_avg_2qtr'] = df_full['t_score'].rolling(2).mean() # this is incorrect
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `rolling` and `expanding` methods. After obtaining the Cartesian product of quarterly indice, you can apply a date mask to get the target rows.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame({'stud_name': ['ABC', 'ABC','ABC','ABC', 'DEF'], 'ques_date' : ['13/11/2020', '10/1/2018','11/11/2017', '27/03/2016', '13/05/2010']})
df_score = pd.DataFrame({'stud_name': ['ABC', 'ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'], 'qtr':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q4','Q2','Q4'], 'year' : [2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2017], 't_score':[11,13,15,17,12,312,14,15,18,43,32], 'p_score':[32,45,32,21,56,87,32,786,213,32,11]})

# Assign necessary datetime objects
df['ques_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.ques_date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df[['act_qtr', 'act_year', 'act_key']] = df['ques_date'].map(lambda e: [f'Q{e.quarter}', e.year, e.to_period('Q')]).apply(pd.Series)
df_score['key'] = df_score.year.astype(str) + df_score.qtr

# Calculate the two kinds of the moving average
df_score.sort_values(['year', 'qtr'], inplace=True)
df_score['mov_avg_full'] = df_score.groupby('stud_name')['t_score'].expanding().mean().values
df_score['mov_avg_2qtr'] = df_score.groupby('stud_name')['t_score'].rolling(2).mean().values

# Get a cross-joined dataframe
df_full = df.merge(df_score, on='stud_name').sort_values(['act_key', 'key'])

# Apply a datetime mask
df_full = df_full[df_full.key < df_full.act_key].groupby(['stud_name', 'act_qtr', 'act_year'], as_index=False).last()

# Deal with the missing null values and use necessary columns
df_full = df.merge(df_full, how='left', on=['stud_name', 'ques_date', 'act_qtr', 'act_year'])
df_full = df_full[['stud_name', 'ques_date', 'act_qtr', 'act_year', 'mov_avg_full', 'mov_avg_2qtr']]

print(df_full)
```

### Output:

| stud_name | ques_date | act_qtr | act_year | mov_avg_full | mov_avg_2qtr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2020-11-13 00:00:00 | Q4 | 2020 | 56.2857 | 163 |
| ABC | 2018-01-10 00:00:00 | Q1 | 2018 | 56.2857 | 163 |
| ABC | 2017-11-11 00:00:00 | Q4 | 2017 | 56.2857 | 163 |
| ABC | 2016-03-27 00:00:00 | Q1 | 2016 | 14 | 16 |
| DEF | 2010-05-13 00:00:00 | Q2 | 2010 | nan | nan |

Comment: why should we use `pd.PeriodIndex(df_score.year.astype(str) + df_score.qtr, freq='Q')`? Instead, can't we just use `(df_score.year.astype(str) + df_score.qtr)`? Just concatenate two strings?

Comment: Additonally, when we do `df_score.groupby('stud_name')['t_score'].expanding().mean().values`, how come it is automatically storing the 1st value as `average value` for 1st row (of each stud_name)?

Comment: because for `mov_avg_2qtr`, we get `NaN` as expected but for `mov_avg_full`, we see it is already populated with 1st row value for each stud_name

Comment: The reason why I did such a treatment is that `to_period('Q')` makes `period[Q-DEC]` type values. So I thought I had to adjust the values of interest to this type. But now I found that concatenating two strings is enough because it still works fine. I'll update my answer about this part.

Comment: `expanding()` is equivalent to `rolling(window=inf, min_periods=1)`. If we use `rolling(window)` without the `min_periods` option, we will get `NaN` until the number of cells to be aggregated reaches the window size. That's why we got `NaN` for the 1st row of `mov_avg_2qtr` since the window size = 2 while the number of aggregated cells is only 1.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you elaborate or explain the last comment once again? Regarding NA with 2qtr and full past

Comment: According to the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), `For a window that is specified by an integer, min_periods will default to the size of the window.` In our case, since we wrote `rolling(2)` in the code, so the `min_periods` = `2`. And the document also says that `min_periods` is the `Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value; otherwise, result is np.nan.`

Comment: So in the very first row, the `rolling` window captured only a single value `11`. So this `rolling` aggregation returned `NaN` according to the definition. In the next row, the `rolling` window captured two values `11` and `13`. And this time, the window size and the number of the captured values is the same, so the `rolling` aggregation returned `(11 + 13)/2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242506/discussion-between-the-great-and-quasi-human).